# After executing do-release-upgrade (12.04), the lsb_release -a still shows wrong version

Tags: do-release-upgrade, lsb-release

I have executed `do-release-upgrade` on a 12.04 Ubuntu server system. The upgrade went fine, but the welcome screen still shows 14.04 instead of 14.04.1 (which I would expect).
Looking at the `lsb_release -a` output, it shows the old version

```
 lsb_release -a
No LSB modules are available.
Distributor ID: Ubuntu
Description:    Ubuntu 14.04 LTS
Release:        14.04
Codename:       trusty
```

Going deeper I have checked the `/etc/lsb-release` file and investigated what version of  `base-files` package (to which this file "belongs") is installed. I've found out that my version is `7.2ubuntu5` whereas in my opinion it should be `7.2ubuntu5.1` as this version has correct release identification in the `/etc/lsb-release` file (and other files).

I suppose that the new version should have come with the `do-release-upgrade`, but it didn't for some reason. Moreover, `apt` does not offer the newer version, I do not know why.

Any ideas what went wrong?

Comment: I'm sorry you are completely right here. The upgrade was from the 12.04 version and not 14.04 (I already changed it in the post). But why is the point release 14.04.1 not offered to me?

Comment: @john: Have you done a `sudo apt-get update` and `sudo apt-get upgrade`? What about `sudo apt-get dist-upgrade`?

Comment: @saiarcot895, yes I did all of these, here just the result from the last two commands, it's always the same: 


`apt-get upgrade
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree
Reading state information... Done
Calculating upgrade... Done
0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 0 not upgraded.
apt-get dist-upgrade
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree
Reading state information... Done
Calculating upgrade... Done
0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 0 not upgraded.`

Comment: Open up `/etc/apt/sources.list`, and make sure that there is a line similar to `deb http://ftp.utexas.edu/ubuntu/ trusty-updates main universe restricted multiverse` The important thing here is the `trusty-updates` part. Replace the link with the appropriate mirror for you. After doing this, run the commands again.

Comment: This is something I've checked as first. I think my sources.list is fine. There are following entries:<br/>
`deb http://cz.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ trusty-updates main restricted`<br/> 
`deb-src http://cz.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ trusty-updates main restricted`<br/>  
`deb http://cz.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ trusty-updates universe`<br/>  
`deb-src http://cz.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ trusty-updates universe`<br/> 
`deb http://cz.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ trusty-updates multiverse`<br/> 
`deb-src http://cz.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ trusty-updates multiverse`<br/>